# Debian: Run a new screen using PHP

Tags: php, linux, exec, gnu-screen

I'm currently trying to build a screen manager for my V-Server (running Debian 6.0.6) using PHP.

My script does already show the runnung screens, but I just fail at running a new screen:

webstat.php:

```
exec('sudo -u root screen -ls',$result);
print_r($result);
```

Added to sudoers (I know that this is unsecure, but it's easier in the testing phase):

```
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Here is the code I've tried to run a PHP-file in a new screen:

```
exec('sudo -u root screen -S screenId php /var/www/script.php parameter1=1',$result);
print_r($result);
```

This just outputs "Must be connected to a terminal.", but using SSH this command is working perfectly.

Next I read about the SSH-command and tried this command:

```
sudo -u root ssh -t root@box screen -S screenId php /var/www/script.php parameter1=1
```

That command worked using PuTTY, but when I use this command in PHP it gives no result nor starts a new screen session:

```
exec('sudo -u root ssh -t root@box screen -S screenId php /var/www/script.php parameter1=1',$result);
print_r($result);
```

There are no functions disabled on my V-Server.
I don't want to write a bash-script which I call with PHP, I want to execute the commands directly with PHP.

It would be nice if someone knows how to fix this problem!

Comment: You need to disable `requiretty` in the sudoers file.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I've just tried it for users root and www-data, but it still does not run a new screen. I've tried it this way:
Defaults:root !requiretty
Defaults:www-data !requiretty